# I can't catch the value of the checkbox input

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, react-hooks, jsx

I have a React form where I can't control the value of the checkbox input with the useState hook. I don't have this problem with other inputs.

I can't pass the checkbox input value to the AuthData object. When you click the "Sign in" button, the console should display an AuthData object with the fields { login: '', password: '', isRemember: '' }

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'

export const AuthForm = ({ handlers }) => {
  const [authData, setAuthData] = useState({ login: '', password: '', isRemember: '' })

  const changeValue = (event) => {
    const { id, value } = event.target
    setAuthData((prevAuthData) => ({ ...prevAuthData, [id]: value }))
  }

  const signIn = () => {
    console.log(authData)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        id="login" 
        placeholder="Login/E-mail/Phone" 
        value={authData.login} 
        onChange={changeValue} 
      />
      <input 
        type="password" 
        id="password" 
        placeholder="Password" 
        value={authData.password} 
        onChange={changeValue} 
      />
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        id="isRemember" 
        value={authData.isRemember} 
        onChange={changeValue} 
      />
      <button onClick={signIn}>Sign in</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

When you change inputs values, their values must be passed to the authValue object.
With "login" and "password" inputs their values go into the authValue object, but with "isRemember" input this does not work. The value of checkbox inputs somehow does not get into the authValue object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the input `type` and get the `checked` value for `checkbox` from the event object as below

```
const changeValue = (event) => {
  let { id, value, type, checked="" } = event.target;
  if (type === "checkbox") {
    value = checked;
  }
  setAuthData((prevAuthData) => ({ ...prevAuthData, [id]: value }));
};
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/GeorgiiGalechyan/2dcc3adc96e14dd7821ae6c4ddaf74a1

Comment: @GeorgiiGalechyan you are wc ...

Comment: wc?... Sorry, English is not my first language.

Comment: my bad it's welcome 

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `checked` attribute on the checkbox input.

The value attribute is used, but you’ll have to modify it to ensure it sends `true` or `false` to the state object

I've added a snippet in response to your comment.

```js
const {useState} = React

const AuthForm = ({ handlers }) => {
  const [authData, setAuthData] = useState({ login: '', password: '', isRemember: false })

  const changeValue = (event) => {
    const { id, value } = event.target
    setAuthData((prevAuthData) => ({ ...prevAuthData, [id]: value }))
  }
  
  const changeCheckbox = () => {
    setAuthData((prevAuthData) => ({ ...prevAuthData, isRemember: !prevAuthData.isRemember }))
  }

  const signIn = () => {
    console.log(authData)
  }
  
  console.log(authData);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        id="login" 
        placeholder="Login/E-mail/Phone" 
        value={authData.login} 
        onChange={changeValue} 
      />
      <input 
        type="password" 
        id="password" 
        placeholder="Password" 
        value={authData.password} 
        onChange={changeValue} 
      />
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        id="isRemember" 
        checked={authData.isRemember} 
        onChange={changeCheckbox} 
      />
      <button onClick={signIn}>Sign in</button>
    </form>
  )
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <AuthForm />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: @HarrisonI I tried using `checked`. That partially solved the problem, but not completely. Could you write a piece of input checkbox code with the `checked` attribute? Maybe I'm using it wrong.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/GeorgiiGalechyan/2dcc3adc96e14dd7821ae6c4ddaf74a1

Comment: @GeorgiiGalechyan no problem, added a snippet, for ease I've given the checkbox its own handler